Show $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)) = 1$
How can I determine that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)) = 1$$  Wolfram Alpha shows me this, but I can't derive it.  L'Hopital's rule isn't useful, since we get stuck in $\frac 0 0$ forms.  I also tried to find a power series that would help, but didn't succeed.

Details on my attempt
Since $x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1))$ is of the form $\infty \cdot 0$, rewrite it as $$\frac {\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)}{1/x}.$$  Apply L'Hopital's rule to get $$\frac {\frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+1}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}.$$
But that's still $\frac 0 0$, and subsequent derivatives seem to be the same.
I also tried creating a Taylor series of the function by taking its derivatives, but this got very messy quickly.

Note that $\log(x+2) - \log(x+1) = \log((x+2)/(x+1)) = \log(1 + 1/(x+1))$.  As $x\rightarrow\infty$, this is $\sim 1/(x+1)$.

Take $f(x)=x(\log(x+2)-\log(x+1))$. Try to calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}$. It's easy to calculate and, moreover, that limit will be $2$. To conclude, apply this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696342/if-lim-fx-1-fx-2-prove-that-lim-x-to-0-fx-1
Obviously, the version for limits to infinity. Hope it helps!

Please show the details of the various attempts you are mentionning. Contrarily to your claim, L'Hopital's rule is useful here (though not my prefered approach).

@AnneBauval user IITRoorkee I've added more details on my attempts.

That is good @SRobertJames. Go Ahead.

From 1 to 8 answers after adding you attempt. Impressive

Your attempt to use L'Hopital's rule was promising: as $x\to\infty$,
$$\frac{\frac1{x+2}-\frac1{x+1}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=\frac{x^2}{(x+1)(x+2)}\to1.$$

Interesting example of basic algebra simplifying a $\frac 0 0$ form to something defined.  Perhaps I shouldn't be surprised, as the simplest example of such is $\frac {2/x - 1/x}{1/x} \to 1$. Lesson learned: After applying L'Hopital, can the resultant expression be simplified using other means?

Isn't the OP asking for a limit without l'Hospital?

Let $t=x+1$
\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \infty} x (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)) &= \lim_{x \to \infty}  \log \big({x+2\over x+1}\big)^x\\ 
 &= \log(\lim_{x \to \infty}  \big({x+2\over x+1}\big)^x)\\ 
 &= \log(\lim_{t \to \infty}  \big(1+{1\over t}\big)^{t-1})\\ 
 &= \log( e)=1\\ 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)) & = \\
=\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot \log \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right). \tag 1
\end{align}
in the existence field of the logarithm. We have that
$$
\frac{x+2}{x+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{x+1}.
$$
Now, we can use the fact that if $u\to 0$,
$$
\log(1 + u) \approx u.
$$
Taking $$u=\frac1{x+1}$$
being $x \to \infty$ then $u\to 0$. Hence:
$$
\log \left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right) =\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{x+1}\right) \approx \frac{1}{x+1}.
$$
Substituting this back into our limit $(1)$, we get:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+1}= 1.
$$
Therefore, we conclude that:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)) = 1.
$$

Using the fundamental limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log(1+t)}t=1$ you get:
\begin{align} \lim_{x \to \infty} x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1))&= \lim_{x\to \infty}(x+1-1)\log\left(\frac{x+2}{x+1}\right)\\&=\lim_{x\to \infty}(x+1)\log\left(1+\frac1{x+1}\right)+\lim_{x\to \infty}\log\left(1+\frac1{x+1}\right)\\ & =\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log(1+t)}t+\log 1=1\end{align}
where $t=\frac1{x+1}$.

If you want to use Taylor expansion directly, without the fundamental limit, you can start by substituting $t=1/x$:
\begin{align} x(\log(2+x)-\log(1+x))=\frac1t\left(\log(2+\frac 1t)-\log(1+\frac 1t)\right)=\frac1t(\log(1+2t)-\log(1+t)) \end{align}
Now, as $y\to 0$, $\log(1+y) =y+o(y)$, so:
$$\frac1t(\log(1+2t)-\log(1+t))=\frac 1t(2t-t+o(t))=\frac{t+o(t)}t\to 1 $$

We have that
$$ x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)) =\frac{\log \left(1+\frac 2x\right) - \log \left(1+\frac 1x\right)}{\frac1x}=$$
$$= \frac{\log \left(1+\frac 2x\right) - 0}{\frac1x}-\frac{ \log \left(1+\frac 1x\right)-0}{\frac1x}$$
therefore, using derivatives, by $t=\frac1x \to 0$ and $f(t)=\log \left(1+2t\right)$, $g(t)=\log \left(1+t\right)$ we have
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x \cdot (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1))=$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}-\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t-0}=f'(0)-g'(0)=2-1=1$$

Similar to nonuser's answer. The derivative of $\log x$ at $x=1$ is $1.$ In other words,
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \left( \frac{\log(1+h)}{h}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0} \left( \frac{\log(1+h) - \log(1)}{(1+h) - 1}\right) = 1. $$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x (\log (x+2) - \log(x+1)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( x \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x+1} \right) \right)$$
$$ = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{x}{x+1} \frac{\log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x+1} \right)}{\frac{1}{x+1}} \right) = 1\cdot 1 = 1.$$

More generally, consider
$f(x; a, b)
=x(\log(x+a)-\log(x+b))$.
Since,
for $0 < t < 1$,
$1-t
\lt \dfrac1{1+t}
\lt 1$,
integrating from $0$ to $x$
for $0 < x < 1$ we get
$\int_0^x (1-t)dt
\lt \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\lt \int_0^x  dt
$
or
$x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}
\lt \log(1+x)
\lt x
$.
Then,
for $x > \max(a, b)$,
$\begin{array}\\
f(x; a, b)
&=x(\log(x+a)-\log(x+b))\\
&=x((\log(x)+\log(1+a/x))-(\log(x)+\log(1+b/x)))\\
&=x(\log(1+a/x)-\log(1+b/x))\\
\text{so}\\
f(x; a, b)
&\lt x(\dfrac{a}{x}-(\dfrac{b}{x}-\dfrac{b^2}{2x^2}))\\
&= a-b+\dfrac{b^2}{2x}\\
\text{and}\\
f(x; a, b)
&\gt x(\dfrac{a}{x}-\dfrac{a^2}{2x^2}-\dfrac{b}{x})\\
&= a-b-\dfrac{a^2}{2x}\\
\end{array}
$
Therefore
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x; a. b)
=a-b
$.
If $a=2, b=1$
the limit is $1$.
